# SikuliSharp.SikuliFindFailedException C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sikuli

I am using `SikuliCSharp` package `v1.1.2` in Visual Studio 2015
I am trying to do following:

```
using (var session = Sikuli.CreateSession())
{
    var pattern = Patterns.FromFile(@"C:\pathtoimage\image.png");
    var value = session.Click(pattern);
}
```

But while running i get an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'SikuliSharp.SikuliFindFailedException' occurred in SikuliSharp.dll.
Additional information: [error] Image: Image not valid, but TextSearch is switched off!
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

It should work if you delete `var value =` in front of `session.Click(pattern);`

Comment: be more descriptive please with better explanation.